# How do you nest complexType elements in an xsd?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, complextype

I have an xml and xsd file that both validate correctly (tested at http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/).

However, the xml does not validate against the xsd. I think this is because I am incorrectly nesting complexType elements in the xsd, as compared to the xml. The outer element of `people` seems to be causing the problem...

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<people>
    <person>
        <firstname>Joe</firstname>
        <lastname>Schmoe</lastname>
    </person>

    <person>
        <firstname>Cletus</firstname>
        <lastname>Jenkins</lastname>
    </person>
</people>
```

...and here is the xsd:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name = "people">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name = "person">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>

                            <xs:element name = "firstname" type = "xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name = "lastname" type = "xs:string" />

                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the element named "person". It is a sequence of one or more person elements.

Note: write maxOccurs in lowerCamelCase not in lower case

Answer (score 4):

Try this for your XSD:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="people" type="people"/>

    <xs:complexType name="people">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="person" type="person" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Btw, I've added some example restrictions to the number of occurrences of certain elements, but of course these can be changed or omitted depending on your requirements.

Comment: That's an interesting solution @JonoB... is this always a better practice to add a restriction as an attribute of an element, instead of using the `<xs:restriction base = "xs:string">...</xs:restriction>` tags?